# facing problem in data binding while sharing content on whats-app through mobile browser

Tags: javascript, angular, whatsapp

I am working on Angular application  where I am sharing content on watsapp app , **through mobile's browser ..** 
content is shared on mobile whatsapp app easily

> but when  I am trying to bind data to it via **interpolation** , data
>   is not shared

I am sharing code below ->

**ts**

```
  team1 : any  = 'India';
  team2 : any  = 'japan';
```

**html**

```
<a 
href="whatsapp://send?text=" 
title="Share On Whatsapp" 
onclick="window.open('whatsapp://send?text=%20{{team1}}%20vs%20{{team2}}%20Take%20a%20look%20at%20this%20awesome%20page%20-%20' 
+ encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;">
whatsapp share
</a>
```

> **Issue** -> onclick method doesn't support Interpolation due to security
>   reasons So How I can solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```html
<a 
href="whatsapp://send?text=" 
title="Share On Whatsapp" 
onclick="window.open('whatsapp://send?text=%20' + team1 +'%20vs%20' + team2 + '%20Take%20a%20look%20at%20this%20awesome%20page%20-%20' 
+ encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;">
whatsapp share
</a>
```

You don't need the double-curly braces ,because you are passing the variables.
Or you could prepare your string in typescript.

```js
private whatsupUrl : string;
this.whatsupUrl = `whatsapp://send?text=%20${this.team1}%20vs%20${this.team2}%20Take%20a%20look%20at%20this%20awesome%20page%20-%20`;
```

```html
<a 
href="whatsapp://send?text=" 
title="Share On Whatsapp" 
onclick="window.open(whatsupUrl + encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;">
whatsapp share
</a>
```